# AWS RDS Postgres Performance Slow Data Transfer

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, query-optimization, amazon-rds

I am experiencing slow (2-3min) returns from a simple query on an AWS RDS postgres materialized view.   My working hypothesis is that this is a network transfer issue but I am not an expert in postgres. Some background on the setup:

- "PostgreSQL 10.21 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 7.4.0, 64-bit",
- Running this in Serverless mode on RDS, 16 Aurora Units
- This process is run through an **AWS VPN Connection**
- The table in question has about **50M rows**, 30 columns and is currently 20GB in total size
- I have placed an multicolumn index on the view (2 columns of interest).  One of these "COMPOUND" has ~100K unique values and approx 1000 rows per compound, the other "GENE" has ~500 unique values with ranges 100K-2M rows per gene

When I run:

```
SELECT * FROM my_materialized_view where "COMPOUND" = 'cpd1234';
```

The query returns ~3-5seconds.

When I run:

```
SELECT * FROM my_materialized_view where "GENE" = 'geneXYZ';
```

The query takes ~2min to return 1M rows.   The size of the returned data appears to 100-200MB in size.

Doing something slightly more "exotic":

```
SELECT * FROM my_materialized_view where "GENE" = 'geneXYZ' ORDER BY 'measured_value' LIMIT 10000;
```

returns data in about 12sec.

I also ran:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM my_materialized_view where "GENE" = 'geneXYZ';
```

the output seemed to indicate the process was about 500ms

> "Index Scan using my_materialized_view_idx on my_materialized_view  (cost=0.56..1415484.25 rows=922393 width=336) (actual time=0.039..437.332 rows=979434 loops=1)"
> "  Index Cond: (""GENE"" = 'geneXYZ'::text)"
> "Planning time: 0.092 ms"
> "Execution time: 491.306 ms"

Am I reading this wrong or is the issue with the data transfer/network latency? I am using pgadmin for the queries, but also ran the query via python boto3 and equivalent times are realized. Appreciate your thoughts on this.  Thanks!

Comment: "This process is run through an AWS VPN Connection" the additional latency will especially hurt queries that require lots of round trips.  If you're pulling 1M rows, that 's a lot of fetching rows and that means lots of round trips and thus, 1M multiplier on the latency.  So if you have say 5ms of latency that can easily baloon into the hundreds of seconds lost waiting for network traffic.  First thing I'd try is running from an ec2 instance in the same subnet just to see how it's different.

Comment: Thank you erik258 for the pointer on this, the EC2 instance approach seems like a great test case as well.  The end user who reported this is having issues pulling into a data visualization tool on their desktop.  I am wondering if they are better served pre-filtering the data with a cut off for the measured values

Comment: The data and the tool are too "far" apart - we seem to all agree on that problem.  I for one would tend to try to move the tool closer to the data - Athena and AWS Glue come to mind, or you could spin up EC2 instances for custom tools and use RDP maybe.  Or you could move the data closer to the user - maybe an entire dataset or some sort of summary would, in your case, be responsible (eg no pii) to simply download locally - even 2, 3, 10 GB of data can be downloaded pretty quick in the overall run of things

Comment: These are good points erik258, I was thinking RDP as a possibility as well for this as it is not a dataset that is hit frequently by a large group and perhaps setting up a place where users can jump on and perform an analysis is the best path forward.

Comment: AWS Workspaces is another option if you need a little more management process then just "spin up an EC2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two facts about your situation make it clear that you do have slow data transfer, not a slow RDBMS server.

1. You have an index on that `GENE` column, and your query plan says postgreSQL is using it.
2. Your second query, with its `ORDER BY some_unindexed_column LIMIT some_number`, burdens postgreSQL with a sort. It returns about 1% of the data of your first query, and completes ten times faster. That means the sort costs something, but the transfer also costs something.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer O. Jones, I appreciate the clarity of the answer.  This was sort of in line with my thinking but did not know if there was some sort of asynchronous fetch happening that was causing the issue.  I guess we will turn our attention towards the VPN/Network latency!  Appreciate it!!!

Comment: A megarow result set is quite large, especially when transferred from inside your AWS AZ to a machine local to you.  Don't forget, AWS charges US$90 per terabyte for bandwidth egress from their network. It might be smart to operate a local replica of that database, or even bring it back home from the cloud entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder on the egress cost, while we are not hitting this database hard now it could change so limiting this egress cost is certainly in play.  Thanks again for your thoughts on this!